# How do I Arrange All MS Project Files Side-by-Side?

Tags: ms-project

I'm aware that MS Project does not allow you to have multiple instances of the application open unlike the rest of MS Office. I know that you can view multiple projects at once by clicking the *Arrange All* button in *Window* group of the *View* Tab

[image: Arrange All]

When I click the button, it stacks the project files on top of each other like this:

[image: Stacked]

However, I want the button to arrange them side-by-side, like this:

[image: side-by-side]

I can't seem to find a way to do this automatically. I always need to resize and reposition the windows manually. What setting do I need to change to make this happen? I've tried clicking the arrange all button twice, but it does not change the orientation of the windows. I know it's possible because I've seen other MS Project users do it. I'm using MS Project Professional 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a quick search I see many people have asked this same question but no answers posted. However, it can be done with a simple macro:

```
Public Sub ArrangeVertically()

    WindowArrangeAll
    Windows(1).WindowState = pjMaximized
    Windows(2).WindowState = pjMaximized
    
    Dim w As Double
    w = Windows(2).Width
    Dim h As Double
    h = Windows(2).Height
    
    WindowArrangeAll
    
    Windows(1).Width = w / 2
    Windows(2).Width = w / 2
    
    Windows(2).Left = w / 2
    
    Windows(1).Top = 0
    Windows(2).Top = 0
    
    Windows(1).Height = h
    Windows(2).Height = h
    
End Sub
```

Modify the code as desired to handle cases where the window count <> 2.

Comment: Thanks Rachel. My current theory is that this feature is inherent in MS Project 2019 and above. I downloaded 2019 Professional and it works out of the box now. I will use this script for versions earlier than 2019.